# Denominator in Maximum Posterior Estimation - How to Interpret?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, bayesian

Suppose we're given a sequence $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ of realizations of i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ random variables and we want to apply maximum posterior estimation to estimate the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$.  For this, suppose we decide $\mu$ and $\sigma$ have joint pdf $g = g(\mu,\sigma)$ on some set $A$.  Then we seek to maximize
$$
\frac{g(\mu,\sigma) \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n \phi(x_i \mid \mu,\sigma)}{\int_A g(x,y) \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n \phi(x_i \mid x,y)\, dx \, dy}
$$
where $\phi(\cdot \mid \mu,\sigma) $ is the normal pdf.

The denominator, which is the **marginal pdf of the data** is dropped since it doesn't affect the maximum.  My question is, how am I supposed to interpret the denominator as the marginal pdf of the data?  I already assumed the observations were jointly normal, so it seems like the marginal pdf should be
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n \phi(x_i ; \mu^*,\sigma^*)
$$
for some parameters $\mu^*$ and $\sigma^*$.  Is it that, I'm really **forcing** the marginal to be the denominator, whatever this integral works out to be?  That still clashes with my understanding that the data is normal to begin with.

Comment: The prior was not normal.  For example, suppose the prior says that with probability $1/2$ we have $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$ and with probability $1/2$ we have $\mu=10$ and $\sigma=1$.  Then the marginal distribution of the data will be bimodal. ${}\qquad{}$